# How get data in controller of both ng-repeat field along with outside ng-repeat field

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am working on angular Project.I have two divs. In one div there is dynamic input which generating through ng-repeat. Initially, two input will be available but if the euser clicks on add more than dynamic two input will be generated through ng-repeat  And in another div there is two input type text which is already present there (not generating through ng-repeat).

Problem I am facing is How to take the value of both div input on submit.Pls help me in this how to take all data at once on submit. My code:

```js
var addnew = angular.module('dump',[]);

addnew.controller('dumpcontroller', function($scope) 
{
  $scope.choices = [{id: 'choice1'}];
   $scope.addNewChoice = function() {
  var newItemNo = $scope.choices.length+1;
  $scope.choices.push({'id':'choice'+newItemNo});
  };


   $scope.removeChoice = function() {
      var lastItem = $scope.choices.length-1;
      $scope.choices.splice(lastItem);
   };
  });
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script src ="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>
<body ng-app="dump" ng-controller="dumpcontroller">      
<div class="divone" data-ng-repeat="choice in choices"> 
    <input type="text" placeholder="Name" ng-model="choice.childname">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Name" ng-model="choice.childbirth">
    <button ng-click="removeChoice()">-</button> //To remove the field dynamically.
</div>

 <button class="remove" ng-click="addNewChoice()">Add more</button> //To add the more childname and childbirth field.

<div class="divtwo">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Name" ng-model="choice.firstname">
   <input type="text" placeholder="Name" ng-model="choice.lastname">
</div>

<button type="button" id="submit" name="submit" ng-click="famupdate(choices)">Submit</button>
  
  </body>
  </html>
```

Now I want to get all details of both div on click in controller.How can I achieve this. Help me out.

Thanking you in anticipation.

Comment: Share your code in plnkr.

Comment: I have added snippet

Comment: you want both in same array?

Comment: use ng-repeat with offset, start ng-repeat from `$index` = 1, and display first object of that array as static in div two

Comment: Can you explain this by an example or modify my snippets. Thanking you in anticipation. @EbinManuval

Comment: @Mohammed posted it as answer check that out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

start `ng-repeat` from custom offset so that you will get both in same array

```
<div ng-repeat="choice in choices | limitTo: (1 - choices.length)">
 ....
</div>
<div class="divtwo">
   <input type="text" placeholder="Name" ng-model="choices[0].firstname">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Name" ng-model="choices[0].lastname">
</div>
```

detailed example is given in the fiddle [check this out](https://fiddle.jshell.net/ebinmanuval/fL6ffn8a/)

Answer (score 1):

What you have to do is just use the `$scope.choice` object in the click function. I have made some modifications in your code. On adding a new item in the object, I have initialized them with null string. Also the `ng-model` initialized for the second div is a little bit confusing by using the `choice.firstname` and `choice.lastname`. I have replaced them with just `firstname` and `lastname`. Please look at this code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var addnew = angular.module('dump', []);
        addnew.controller('dumpcontroller', function ($scope) {
            $scope.choices = [{
                id: 'choice1'
            }];
            $scope.addNewChoice = function () {
                var newItemNo = $scope.choices.length + 1;
                $scope.choices.push({
                    'childname': "",
                    'childbirth': ""
                });
            };
            $scope.removeChoice = function () {
                var lastItem = $scope.choices.length - 1;
                $scope.choices.splice(lastItem);
            };
            
            $scope.famupdate = function (choices){
                //No need to pass choices object actually. You can just use $scope.choices also.
                console.log("Data Generated Dynamically");
                console.log(choices);
                console.log("Data value in second div");
                console.log($scope.firstname);
                console.log($scope.lastname);
            }
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body ng-app="dump" ng-controller="dumpcontroller">
    <div class="divone" data-ng-repeat="choice in choices">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Name" ng-model="choice.childname">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Name" ng-model="choice.childbirth">
        <button ng-click="removeChoice()">-</button> //To remove the field dynamically.
    </div>

    <button class="remove" ng-click="addNewChoice()">Add more</button> //To add the more childname and childbirth field.

    <div class="divtwo">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Name" ng-model="firstname">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Name" ng-model="lastname">
    </div>

    <button type="button" id="submit" name="submit" ng-click="famupdate(choices)">Submit</button>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is answer, Change as per your requirement.

```js
var addnew = angular.module('dump',[]);

addnew.controller('dumpcontroller', function($scope) 
{
  $scope.choices = [{id: 'choice1', 'childname':'', 'childbirth':'', 'firstname':'', 'lastname':''}];
   $scope.addNewChoice = function() {
  var newItemNo = $scope.choices.length+1;
  $scope.choices.push({'id':'choice'+newItemNo, 'childname':'', 'childbirth':'','firstname':'','lastname':''});
  };


   $scope.removeChoice = function() {
      var lastItem = $scope.choices.length-1;
      $scope.choices.splice(lastItem);
   };
  $scope.famupdate = function(){  
   console.log($scope.choices);
  }
  });
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script src ="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>
<body ng-app="dump" ng-controller="dumpcontroller">   
  <form name="sform">
<div class="divone" data-ng-repeat="choice in choices"> 
    <input type="text" placeholder="Name" ng-model="choice.childname">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Name" ng-model="choice.childbirth">
   <button class="remove" ng-click="addNewChoice()">Add more</button> //To add the more childname and childbirth field.
  
    <a ng-click="removeChoice()">Remove</a> //To remove the field dynamically.


<div class="divtwo">
    <input type="text" placeholder="FirstName" ng-model="choice.firstname">
   <input type="text" placeholder="LastName" ng-model="choice.lastname">
</div>
</div>
<button type="button" id="submit" name="submit" ng-click="famupdate(choices)">Submit</button>
  </form>
  {{choices}}
  </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If possible send me ur complete code(js code).or share ur js fiddle.I will change and share with u.

```
<div class="divone" data-ng-repeat="choice in choices track by $index"> 
    <input type="text" placeholder="Name" ng-model="choice.childname[$index]">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Name" ng-model="choice.childbirth[$index]">
    <button ng-click="removeChoice()">-</button> //To remove the field      dynamically.
</div>

<button class="remove" ng-click="addNewChoice()">Add more</button> //To add the more childname and childbirth field.

<div class="divtwo">
   <input type="text" placeholder="Name" ng-model="choice.firstname">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Name" ng-model="choice.lastname">
</div>

<button type="button" id="submit" name="submit" ng-click="famupdate(choices,$index)">Submit</button>

var counter = 0;
$scope.choices = [];

for (var choice in $scope.choices) {
  var firstName = choice.firstName;
  var lastName = choice.lastName;
  var childname = choice.childName[counter];
  var childbirth = choice.childbirth[counter];
  counter++;
}

$scope.addNewChoice = function() {
    var obj = {'childName':'','childbirth':''}
    $scope.choices.push(obj)
}
```

Comment: pls see the snippet.I have added the logic of dynamic input repeatation. I want logic of getting all the value of input field. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One thing I observed is you are taking `"choice.firstname"` in `#div2` but collecting choices. To make it more simple I have taken two different model to collect data and then merge them. Try below

```js
var addnew = angular.module('dump',[]);

addnew.controller('dumpcontroller', function($scope) 
{
  $scope.choices = [{id: 'choice1'}];
   $scope.addNewChoice = function() {
  var newItemNo = $scope.choices.length+1;
  $scope.choices.push({'id':'choice'+newItemNo});
     
  };

   $scope.removeChoice = function() {
      var lastItem = $scope.choices.length-1;
      $scope.choices.splice(lastItem);
   };
  
  $scope.famupdate = function (choices,choices2) {
    choices.push(choices2);
    console.log(choices);
  };
  
 });
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script src ="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>
<body ng-app="dump" ng-controller="dumpcontroller">      
<div class="divone" data-ng-repeat="choice in choices track by $index"> 
    <input type="text" placeholder="Name" ng-model="choices[$index].childname">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Name" ng-model="choices[$index].childbirth">
    <button ng-click="removeChoice()">-</button> //To remove the field dynamically.
</div>

 <button class="remove" ng-click="addNewChoice()">Add more</button> //To add the more childname and childbirth field.

<div class="divtwo">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Name" ng-model="choices2.firstname">
   <input type="text" placeholder="Name" ng-model="choices2.lastname">
</div>

<button type="button" id="submit" name="submit" ng-click="famupdate(choices,choices2)">Submit</button>
  
  </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var addnew = angular.module('dump',[]);

addnew.controller('dumpcontroller', function($scope) 
{
  $scope.choices = [{id: 'choice1'}];
 $scope.choi = {};
   $scope.addNewChoice = function() {
  var newItemNo = $scope.choices.length+1;
  $scope.choices.push({'id':'choice'+newItemNo});
  };


   $scope.removeChoice = function() {
      var lastItem = $scope.choices.length-1;
      $scope.choices.splice(lastItem);
   };

  $scope.famupdate = function(){
  for(var i=0;i<$scope.choices.length;i++){
   var childName = $scope.choices[i].childname;
   var childbirth = $scope.choices[i].childbirth;
   console.log('childName:',$scope.choices,childName,childbirth)
  }
  var firstName = $scope.choi.firstName;
  var lastName = $scope.choi.lastName;
  }
  });
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script src ="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>
<body ng-app="dump" ng-controller="dumpcontroller">      
<div class="divone" data-ng-repeat="choice in choices track by $index"> 
    <input type="text" placeholder="Name" ng-model="choice.childname">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Name" ng-model="choice.childbirth">
    <button ng-click="removeChoice()">-</button> //To remove the field dynamically.
</div>

 <button class="remove" ng-click="addNewChoice()">Add more</button> //To add the more childname and childbirth field.

<div class="divtwo">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Name" ng-model="choi.firstname">
   <input type="text" placeholder="Name" ng-model="choi.lastname">
</div>

<button type="button" id="submit" name="submit" ng-click="famupdate(choices)">Submit</button>
  
  </body>
  </html>
```